# Right way to handle navigation using BLoC

Tags: dart, flutter

Hello guys I'm using BLoC for app I'm currently developing but there some cases which I'm clueless like when you do login you fire API call and wait for result naturally I would send loading state and show loader but after 
that finishes how to handle for example navigating to different screen.
I've currently have something like this

```
typedef void LoginSuccessCallback();
    class LoginBloc(){
    LoginBloc(Api this.api,LoginSuccessCallback loginSuccesCallback){
      _login.switchMap((ev) => api.login(ev.payload.email,ev.payload.password)).listen((_) => loginSuccessCallback);
     }
    }
```

But I'm sure there is much cleaner way for handling this I've tried to search some samples which have something similar but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You may want to make the title a bit more specific: "How to handle navigation after login/logout using BLoC" or something similar.

Comment: Maybe you want something like this: https://dev.to/pedromassango/flutter-bloc-a-better-way-to-handle-navigation-4fig

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit: After a few months with this solution in place, I noticed that there are a few problems with it:**

1. **Android hardware back button does not work**
2. The app resets when you toggle "inspect" mode.
3. No transitions possible
4. No guarantee that no forbidden route is displayed

So I no longer recommend using this approach!

---

For normal user-initiated navigation, you don't need the BLoC pattern at all. Just use the `Navigator`.

Login is a special case. Following the BLoC pattern, it would make sense to provide a `isAuthenticated` stream:

```
abstract class MyBloc {
  Stream<bool> get isAuthenticated;
}
```

Your app will probably have 2 different named route trees: One for logged in users, and one for anonymous users:

```
final Map<String, WidgetBuilder> anonymousRoutes = {
  '/': (context) => new LoginScreen(), // default for anon
  '/register': (context) => new RegisterScreen(),
};

final Map<String, WidgetBuilder> authenticatedRoutes = {
  '/': (context) => new HomeScreen(), // default for logged in
  '/savings': (context) => new SavingsScreen(),
  // ...
};
```

Usually the `Navigator` and its named routes are tightly coupled to the `MaterialApp`, but you can also define your own that is rebuilt when the `isAuthenticated` stream is updated:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key, this.bloc}) : super(key: key);

  final MyBloc bloc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return StreamBuilder<bool>(
          stream: bloc.isAuthenticated,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text('loading...');
            }

            bool isAuthenticated = snapshot.data;
            return _buildNavigator(isAuthenticated);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

Navigator _buildNavigator(bool isAuthenticated) {
  // different route tree and different default route depending on auth state
  final routes = isAuthenticated ? authenticatedRoutes : anonymousRoutes;

  return Navigator(
    key: new ValueKey(isAuthenticated),
    onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
      final name = settings.name;
      return new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: routes[name],
        settings: settings,
      );
    },
    onUnknownRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
      throw Exception('unknown route');
    },
  );
}
```

---

Sadly right now (2018-07-14) [there are a 2 conflicting asserts](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18904) in the Flutter code which you have to remove to make the code above work (you can just edit it with your IDE):

Line 93 and 96 in `packages\flutter\lib\src\widgets\app.dart`

```
//assert(navigatorObservers != null),
//assert(onGenerateRoute != null || navigatorObservers == const <NavigatorObserver>[]),
```

Comment: You could provide the `home` property to avoid the assert

Comment: I think that would again trigger other assertions or cause a navigator to be generated