# Flutter BLoC: Navigator.pop in StreamBuilder in build() method

Tags: flutter, bloc

I'm following BLoC pattern and subscribing to stream, and reacting to state changes in build method. When data is loaded I want to close the screen.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Bloc'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: StreamBuilder<UserState>(
          stream: _userBloc.user,
          initialData: UserInitState(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data is UserInitState) {
              return _buildInit();
            }
            if (snapshot.data is UserDataState) {
              Navigator.pop(context, true);
              return Container();
            }
            if (snapshot.data is UserLoadingState) {
              return _buildLoading();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When I do `Navigator.pop(context, true);` in `build()` method I get:

```
I/flutter ( 4360): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY ANIMATION LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 4360): The following assertion was thrown while notifying status listeners for AnimationController:
I/flutter ( 4360): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
I/flutter ( 4360): This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
I/flutter ( 4360): process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
I/flutter ( 4360): only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
I/flutter ( 4360): builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
I/flutter ( 4360): Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
```

What is the right way to handle such cases in BLoC pattern?

On of the solutions I come up with is to start listening to stream on `initState()`. In this case I need to `broadcast()` my stream because I have 2 subscribers.

Are there any better solutions for this?

Comment: You already mentioned the perfect solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigating to a new screen when stream value in BLOC changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101589/navigating-to-a-new-screen-when-stream-value-in-bloc-changes)

Answer (score 18):

I think I have got a solution for you. (Please check it)

Make your code look like :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // other stuff

    if (snapshot.data is UserDataState) {
      myCallback(() {
        Navigator.pop(context, true);
      });
    }

    // other stuff
}
// after build method (but still in the same class,...) write below method

void myCallback(Function callback) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      callback();
    });
}
```

Hope it helps. Just try it and please report here to help others too!

[Source (flutter_bloc Login medium article)](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-login-tutorial-with-flutter-bloc-ea606ef701ad)

[Description](https://medium.com/@felangelov/hi-ant%C3%B3nio-94ab248b766e)

Comment: can we use it in BlocBuilder also?

Answer (score 1):

````
bool hasPop = false;

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Bloc'),
    ),
    body: SafeArea(
      child: StreamBuilder<UserState>(
        stream: _userBloc.user,
        initialData: UserInitState(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data is UserInitState) {
            return _buildInit();
          }
          if (snapshot.data is UserDataState) {
            if(!hasPop){
               hasPop = true;
               Navigator.pop(context, true);
             }
            
            return Container();
          }
          if (snapshot.data is UserLoadingState) {
            return _buildLoading();
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
} ```
````

Comment: please can you explain this code? thanks!

Comment: Every change in StreamBuilder are trigger twice. Navigator.pop can't be call twice.

Comment: @GoldenLion it's not my question. So I can't give you that. It's just the bloc pattern like https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_shopping_cart/lib/cart/bloc

Comment: I used implements and created a subclass for the different state response by bloc

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine three possible solutions:

1) It looks to me like it would be best to restructure your widgets. As far as I can see you want a "Loading Screen" .. I see no reason that this has to be it's own navigation item, instead of just another widget.

Ie. You could push the `StreamBuilder` one? level up.. so your builder method looks like:

```dart
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
  return LoadingScreen(snapshot);
}
// Whatever you do with your data.
```

2) I think i personally would create a `StatefulWidget`, listen to the stream manually in `initState()` and call `setState()` manually. No need for a `StreamBuilder`

3) as a crazy workaround you could probably use `Future(() { Navigator.of(context).pop(); });` in your builder. (it's possible that you'd have to use the `context` of the `build` method, not the builder. but I wouldn't recommend that solution anyway)