# Navigate based on data from stream

Tags: flutter

Stream builder is used to draw widget based on data from stream.

What is the right way to achieve navigation based on the data?

Details:
There is a logout button in drawer. It clears the session and emits a data in the stream.

There's a stateless widget with stream builder listening on data and updating UI. How to make it navigate to login screen based on data in the stream?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigating to a new screen when stream value in BLOC changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54101589/navigating-to-a-new-screen-when-stream-value-in-bloc-changes)

Answer (score -1):

In your stateless widget's build method, you can listen changes in your stream with `listen()` method.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Repository.bulletins.listen((pet) {
      pet.documents[pet.documents.length - 1].data['animalType'] == "Dog"
          ? Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => LostPetForm(),
              ))
          : print('not yet');
    });
    return Scaffold(...
```

Comment: ```I/flutter (14304): The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
I/flutter (14304): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked.
I/flutter (14304): This _ModalScope<dynamic> widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is
I/flutter (14304): locked.```

I get this exception when I navigated from listener method inside build method. I read it is not possible to navigate from inside build method.

Comment: Where did you read it? I've post it after I've tried on a small app with 2 screens and firestore on the backend, it navigated itself when I changed the data from Firestore, without a problem. This error means that you are calling setState during the build phase. If you didn't use setState, Navigator.pop uses setState internally according to this SO post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51246379/9779791

Maybe you can try using Navigator somewhere else in the code, maybe in initState()

Answer (score -1):

Inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54109955/1918649

In the build method of the widget that creates Profile

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userBloc = BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context);
    return ...
           somewhere here Profile(userBloc)
           ...
}
```

```
class Profile extends StatefulWidget  {

  final userBloc;

  Profile(this.userBloc);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ProfileState();
}

class ProfileState extends State<Profile> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.userBloc.stream.listen((userData){
      if(userData==null) {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => LandingPage(),
            ));
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Profile"),
      ),
      drawer: CustomDrawer(),
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<UserModel>(
          initialData: widget.userBloc.user,
          stream: widget.userBloc.stream,
          builder: (ctx, snap) => snap.hasData?Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(snap.data?.imageUrl),
              Text(snap.data?.username)
            ],
          ):Text('You are logged out'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```